# Trouble with strings passed as parameters from command line

Tags: excel, vbscript

I'm trying to convert a flat file into an Excel-readable format. We receive the text file that uses the tilde (~) as a field delimiter, and I want to convert it into one that uses the Tab character. I'm interested in running this from the command line, and I need to be flexible with the filenames, so I want to use parameters. The VBScript I have for it is as follows:

```
Set Args = WScript.Arguments
Set inf = Args(0)
Set outf = Args(1)

Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(infile.Value , ForReading)
strContents = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close

strContents = Replace(strContents, "~", vbTab)

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(outfile.Value , ForWriting)
objFile.Write strContents
objFile.Close
```

For some reason, I get the error *Object required: '[string: "infile.txt"]'*. Using either infile, infile.Value or infile.ToString as the argument in `objFSO.OpenTextFile(infile, ForReading)` doesn't seem to work.

VBScript not being my strong point, does anyone have any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Command-line parameters are strings and not objects, so there's no need to use the `Set` keyword for assignments:

   ```
   inf = Args(0)
   outf = Args(1)
   ```
2. Note also that the above code already gives you the parameter values, so there's no need to use `.Value`, `.ToString` etc (in fact, doing this will result in a run-time error).
3. There're typos in your script — the `inf` and `outf` variables are later referred to as `infile` and `outfile`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I originally had the conversion part in a Sub, but pulled it out when I started running into errors.